# How do I parse JSON like geo:point?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, last.fm

I'm trying to parse a JSON response using jquery from last.fm and getting longitude and latitude values. The part of the JSON that holds those values looks like this:

```
"location":{"geo:point":{"geo:lat":"58.409901","geo:long":"15.563306"}
```

The code I got is this:

```
$.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getevents&artist=familjen&api_key=xformat=json&callback=?",
 function(data){
  $.each(data.events.event, function(i,item){
   $("#menucontent").append("<br/>"+item.title + " " + item.venue.location.geo:point.geo:lat);
        });
});
```

Obviously the part "item.venue.location.geo:point.geo:lat" doesn't work. How do I get those values with ":" ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) when identifiers can't be expressed in [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation), it'd look like this:

```
item.venue.location["geo:point"]["geo:lat"]
```

For illustration, all of these are ways to access the same thing:

```
obj.thing.prop
obj.thing["prop"]
obj["thing"]["prop"]
obj["thing"].prop
```